# Ruby Shoes center window on screen

Tags: ruby, windows, shoes

Is there any way to center an app on screen with Shoes 3.7? 
I can't find anything useful in any docs.
When i start my app, it will appear on the bottom right of the screen.

With Shoes 3.7 i can't even drag the window around, with Shoes 3.8 beta instead, i can drag it around but it will always appear at the bottom of the screen.

With Shoes 3.2 instead, it will appear correctly centered.

Also this simple script won't be centered when launched with Shoes 3.7 and 3.8 beta:

```
Shoes.app {
 stack {
  button("Click me! :)") {para ("Yay!!")}
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out?

Comment: @Shurikan117 not at all. I ended up removing Shoes, and went back to TK gui.

Comment: I'm just starting with Shoes 3.3.7 and the window built with your script appears right in the center of the screen.